# Cannot link to static files with Hugo

Tags: templates, url, content-management-system, static-files, hugo

I have this in `config.toml`:

```
baseURL = "https://my-username.github.io/blog/"
```

and there is a static file at `static/img/foo.png`.

Now, in `content/posts/bar.md`, I have the following content:

```
---
title: "Bar"
---

![foo](img/foo.png)
```

The picture isn't showing after I started the `hugo server`, so I inspected elements, and found out that Hugo generated the following URL for it:

```
http://localhost:1313/blog/posts/bar/img/hireme.png
```

This is not what I expect; it should be

```
http://localhost:1313/blog/img/hireme.png
```

When I use `![foo](/blog/img/foo.png)`, the picture is displayed correctly, but this is quite strange: `/blog/` is part of `baseURL`, why do I need to type it again?

Comment: No idea how Hugo processes the link markup, so just an idea: Did you try `/img/foo.png`?

Comment: @unor It renders to `<img src="/img/foo.png" alt="foo">`, i.e. `http://localhost:1313/img/hireme.png` :(

Answer (score 9):

I think you should use `<base>` tag to make baseURL for static files.

Add the `<base>` tag into `<head>`:

```
<base href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}">
```

And then you can insert image in post like this:

```
![Foo image](img/foo.jpg)
```

References:

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Very helpful, it should be part of the standard Hugo documentation.

Comment: This is **very** dangerous, as it will break any link that happens to be relative to the *page* rather than the website's *base URL*. I recommend to never use the <base> tag as it will make debugging a nightmare (especially after a while when you forgot that you used this tag)...

Answer (score 3):

In a simple setup where your site lives in the domain's root, a absolute reference to the image would be a standard practice. However, in your case where the site is nested, a more crafty solution is necessary.

I suggest using a shortcode to solve your dilemma. Just simply create a shortcode that takes in a resource file path and spits out the desired absolute path every time. The advantage to this approach is flexibility for future resource relocation to a cdn for example.

Your markdown code will be something like this:
`![foo]({{< resource url="img/foo.png" >}})`

Your shortcode template will be something like this:
`{{ .Site.BaseURL }}{{ .Get "url" }}`

Create a file named 'resource.html' in 'layouts/shortcodes/' folder, and drop in the shortcode template code above.

So when you decide you want to switch to a cdn you could easily do this:
`://cdn.example.com/{{ .Get "url" }}`